# Global ajaxError event before local error event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a global ajaxError event, something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function myErrorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("There was a global ajax error!");
});
```

And I have many local ajaxEvents, something like this:

```
$(imageUploadForm).ajaxForm({
            url: assetsUplUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {project_id: projectId, type: 'image', widget: widget},
            error: function(responseText, status, xhr, form){
                 alert("There was a local ajax error!");
            }
        });
```

How can i get the global error event to trigger before the local one without changing in the local ajax?

Comment: From my small understanding I don't think this is possible. Although since I'm not 100%, I'll refrain from creating an actual answer at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I change

```
$(document).ajaxError(function myErrorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("There was a global ajax error!");
});
```

to

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was a global ajax error!");           
            }
    });
```

and global handler calling before local.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. According to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup, global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods rather than within the `options` object for `$.ajaxSetup()`.

My solution was to use $.ajaxPrefilter like this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    let error = options.error;
    options.error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // global error handling first
        console.log('global ajax error');
        
        // override local error handling if exists
        if ($.isFunction(error)) {
            return $.proxy(error, this)(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    };
});
```