# ajaxError() executed after $.ajax error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make an AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/user/logout/",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function() {
    window.location.href = '/';
  },
  error: function() {
    // some staff
  }
});
```

I have also defined global `ajaxError` handler:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings, error) {
  if (jqXHR.status === 403) {
    alert(error);
    // some staff 2
  }
});
```

The problem is that the `error` handler function is executing before the `alert` in the `ajaxError()` is closed and `some staff` runs before `some staff 2`.

UPD.

As mentioned at comments, local error handlers always executed before global. So my question now: how can I check inside global handler is local handler assigned or not?

Comment: Are you sure the code is "executing before the alert is closed" - it's more likely that it's executing before the alert is *opened*.  Change the alert to a `console.log` and add one in your ajaxError handler to see exactly which one is first.

Comment: To clarify: what's the desired behavior here? The global handler gets fired after the local handler [per source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d7237896c79a5a10d85fcdec199c5657a469a92b/src/ajax.js#L793). You can disable the global handler in your $.ajax call with {global: false} (only execute local `error`) or leave out the `error` in your $.ajax call to only execute the global handler.

Comment: You could force the one you want second to go second by putting it inside a timeout, eg `setTimeout(function() { some_stuff(); }, 10);`

Comment: @thmsdnnr your comment most useful for me. Can you watch my edited question and give me some suggestions?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549308/global-ajaxerror-event-before-local-error-event/70983529#70983529) if you want to do global error handling before your local error function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings, error) {
    if(settings.error === undefined) {
        if(jqXHR.status === 403) {
            alert(error);
            // some staff 2
        }
        // more....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dirty cludge with setTimeout for delay

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // some staff
}, 150);
```

But I feel bad saying that.

Comment: That's great. I think it was bad advice from me.

Answer (score -1):

> UPD.
>
> As mentioned at comments, local error handlers always executed before
>   global. So my question now: how can I check inside global handler is
>   local handler assigned or not?

You can change some global variable in your local handler as flag.

And check value of this global flag in global handler. It makes not clean code, but you can make it less bad if create such flags in some "general" global object. Like in

```
obFlagsForEvents = {}; 
obFlagsForEvents["id_of_form_to_check"] = false;
```